# True inverse function for cosine in numpy? (NOT arccos)

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry

Here is a weird one:

I have found myself needing a numpy function that is what I would call the true inverse of `np.cos` (or another trigonometric function, cosine is used here for definiteness). What I mean by ''true inverse'' is a function `invcos`, such that

```
np.cos(invcos(x)) = x
```

for any real float x. Two observations: `invcos(x)` exists (it is a complex float) and `np.arccos(x)` does **not** do the job, because it only works for `-1 < x < 1`.

**My question is if there is an efficient numpy function for this operation or if it can built from existing ones easily?**

My attempt was to use a combination of `np.arccos` and `np.arccosh` to build the function by hand. This is based on the observation that `np.arccos` can deal with x in [-1,1] and `np.arccosh` can deal with x outside [-1,1] if one multiplies by the complex unit. To see that this works:

```
cos_x = np.array([0.5, 1., 1.5])

x = np.arccos(cos_x)
cos_x_reconstucted = np.cos(x)
# [0.5 1.  nan]

x2 = 1j*np.arccosh(cos_x)
cos_x_reconstructed2 = np.cos(x2)
# [nan+nanj 1.-0.j 1.5-0.j]
```

So we could combine this to

```
def invcos(array):
    x1 = np.arccos(array)
    x2 = 1j*np.arccosh(array)
    print(x1)
    print(x2)
    x = np.empty_like(x1, dtype=np.complex128)
    x[~np.isnan(x1)] = x1[~np.isnan(x1)]
    x[~np.isnan(x2)] = x2[~np.isnan(x2)]
    return x

cos_x = np.array([0.5, 1., 1.5])
x = invcos(cos_x)
cos_x_reconstructed = np.cos(x)
# [0.5-0.j 1.-0.j 1.5-0.j]
```

This gives the correct results, but naturally raises RuntimeWarnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos.
```

I guess since numpy even tells me that my algorithm is not efficient, it is probably not efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

---

For readers who are interested in why this strange function may be useful: The motivation comes from a physics background. In certain theories, one can have vector components that are 'off-shell', which means that the components might even be longer than the vector. The above function can be useful to nevertheless parametrize things in terms of angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is if there is an efficient numpy function for this operation or if it can built from existing ones easily?

Yes; it is... `np.arccos`.

From the documentation:

> For real-valued input data types, arccos always returns real output. For each value that cannot be expressed as a real number or infinity, it yields nan and sets the invalid floating point error flag.
>
> For complex-valued input, arccos is a complex analytic function that has branch cuts [-inf, -1] and [1, inf] and is continuous from above on the former and from below on the latter.

So all we need to do is ensure that the input is a complex number (even if its imaginary part is zero):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arccos(2.0)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
nan
>>> np.arccos(2 + 0j)
-1.3169578969248166j
```

For an array, we need the appropriate `dtype`:

```
>>> np.arccos(np.ones((3,3)) * 2)
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
>>> np.arccos(np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.complex) * 2)
array([[0.-1.3169579j, 0.-1.3169579j, 0.-1.3169579j],
       [0.-1.3169579j, 0.-1.3169579j, 0.-1.3169579j],
       [0.-1.3169579j, 0.-1.3169579j, 0.-1.3169579j]])
```

Comment: Well, I completely missed that one... thanks for the answer, that certainly solves it. Since this is almost an atomic solution, I guess there cannot be anything better and will give you the green tick straight away. Thanks and +1!